# Multiple mxds with the same Data Driven Pages properties

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

I have 20 different mxds that display data for 20 different sites.  Is there a way to bring Data Driven Pages properties from one mxd to another so the new mxd will link to different tables and bring in the new attributes so I don't have to insert all of the dynamic text again?

Comment: Not that I know of. If you were starting from scratch you could create one MXD with the dynamic text set up the way you want, then copy the MXD and just change the Index Layer for the DDP.

Comment: I think that maybe if I break the link to the database from the mxd and then reset the source to look at a different database it should then repopulate the data driven pages with the new data as long as the tables have the same schema.